# How to return multiple row by pl/sql stored function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I search for this issue and finally I found a solution on this website but I get a strange error. I searched for the error but because I know very basic of pl/sql I was not able to solve it. here is my function which is trying to return name of the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function FF(BSB_NUMBER IN BANK.BSB#%TYPE) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
IS
    C_RESULT SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN C_RESULT for 
    select * from bank where bank.bsb# = BSB_NUMBER;
    return C_RESULT;    
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error ! There is no such account');
END FF;
/
```

AFTER i RUN=

```
Function created.
```

AFTER EXEC

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FF(012878));


ERROR:

    ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
```

Comment: The function doesn't return a nested-table type, but **a cursor** => `RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR`. You cant do `SELECT * FROM cursor`, see this article: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/ to learn how to use cursors.

Comment: Use a table function if you want to select from it: http://www.orafaq.com/node/1881

Answer (score 0):

Normally ref cursors are passed to client programs, such as JDBC Result Sets.  However, it's easy enough to call a ref cursor in SQL:

```
select  FF(012878) from dual;
```