# How to display table from returned cursor in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to get a table of bank's name which their bsb is equal to value given to the function.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function FF(BSB_NUMBER IN BANK.BSB#%TYPE) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
IS
    MY_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN MY_CURSOR for 
    select * from bank where bank.bsb# = BSB_NUMBER;
    return MY_CURSOR;   
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error ! There is no such account');
END FF;
/
```

And I run in with this but doesn't print anything. Appreciate any idea:

```
SELECT  FindBankStaff(012878) FROM BANK;
```

Comment: Which SQL client are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return multiple row by pl/sql stored function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167474/how-to-return-multiple-row-by-pl-sql-stored-function)

Comment: I'm using sql plus. This question is different because here I am returning a cursor and there I return SYS_REFCURSOR

Comment: But all your questions deal with the problem of returning multiple rows from a function

Comment: You're returning `SYS_REFCURSOR` in both questions; you've just changed how you're calling the function.

Comment: See here to display a ref-cursor in SQL*Plus: http://www.orafaq.com/node/980

Answer (score 0):

Don't return the cursor, return the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I saw this answer and implement it to my issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SOME_FUNC_RETURNING_A_CURSOR RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    csrLocal  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN csrLocal FOR SELECT NAME, BSB# FROM BANK;
    RETURN csrLocal;
  END SOME_FUNC_RETURNING_A_CURSOR;
  /

DECLARE
  aCursor       SYS_REFCURSOR;
  someVariable  VARCHAR2(40); 
  some2 number;
BEGIN
  aCursor := SOME_FUNC_RETURNING_A_CURSOR;
  WHILE TRUE LOOP
    FETCH aCursor INTO someVariable,some2;
    EXIT WHEN aCursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(someVariable);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('    ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(some2);
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: You can do that but it assumes whoever runs it is displaying dbms_output; which isn't really an issue here since it's an anonymous block. From SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you can [use the `variable` and `print` commands](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3527037/266304) around the `exec` to display the cursor more easily.

Answer (score 0):

In Toad there is an option to do this.

You just have to create a bind variable as Ref cursor and invoke the procedure or function. Once the process runs successfully, the Data Grid is automatically populated with the result set of the Object (In your case the records from ref cursor). I suppose even in Oracle Sql Developer the Feature has been incorporated.

If you are using SQL Plus* then the best way is to declare a variable as ref cursor. Execute the piece of block and print the output using **print** command. Hope it helps...